# PayPalFlow Pro vs PayPal Website Pro - How do you solve recurring donation options?

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

[image]
We are trying to migrate from Paypal Website Pro to PayPalFlow Pro so we can use recurring donation.

However, we are getting errors -

What are errors 9016 and 9015, need help with PayPalFlow Pro or PayPal Website Pro

We tried to update to PayFlowPro after enabling "recurring billing". I've verified I've added in the credentials correctly. However, I am not certain about the URL required in the credentials.

I was able to access the CiviContribute page but when testing a donation I received this 9015 and 9016 error. I called Paypal and these errors are not theirs, seems like they are Civi.

I also tried reinstalling the Website Payments Pro account and creds and it no longer allowed me to enable this.
I receive this error when trying to the contribution page.

> Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the
>   moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider
>   with more details about what action you were performing when this
>   occurred. A payment processor configured for this page might be
>   disabled (contact the site administrator for assistance). Return to
>   home page.

[image]

We are running on Drupal 7 and Civi 4.7.30

Comment: I am having the same problem for months now.  We you able to resolve yours?

Comment: So sorry I havent logged in here in a while, we just switched to Stripe. Paypal was a headache